# QGIS multiple labels after PDF export

Tags: qgis, wms

I want to create a map with different data. One layer is a WMS layer with the address: https://geodienste.sachsen.de/wms_geosn_flurstuecke/guest?

This layer contains parcels and the corresponding numbers in Saxony.
If I create a print layout everything is fine, all parcels are correctly labeled. But as soon as I export the map, no matter what format, individual parcels are labeled multiple times. What could be the reason for this? I don't have any other layers in the project from which the labeling could come.

print layout
[image]

pdf export
[image]

I use the QGIS version 3.22.16 LTR

Comment: Looks like the pdf is using tiles

Comment: can I change anything about it via QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

To disable tiled raster layer exports you have to scroll to the bottom of the PDF Export Options dialog and activate the „Disable tiled raster layer exports“ checkbox:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately the setting does not solve the problem

Comment: @joe_gerner I have to confirm your findings, I get duplicated parcel numbers as well. Maybe there is a problem with the WMS service when using higher DPI settings?

Comment: @joe_gerner that's definitely a problem with QGIS. When you use the Developer Tools (press `F12` in main window) you will see that QGIS is fetching multiple images during PDF export and combines the images before writing to the PDF file. You could post this here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: This problem already exists for a long time: https://lists.fossgis.de/pipermail/fossgis-talk-liste/2017-February/008409.html

Answer (score 0):

As this problem seems to be very old and has no solution yet, I would suggest using [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/) to fetch the tiles if you need it often. MapProxy has settings to prevent duplicate labels: https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.0/labeling.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe one way to do this is by setting a fixed reference scale in your WMS layer.

You can do this by going to layer properties, go to the "Representation" tab, and check the "Fixed Reference Scale" option, and play woth the actual reference scale of the layer until it prints as desired.  The reason this isn't playing nice is because the server and not you are controlling what prints, probably because it's got symbology and scale info built in that you don't have access to.